# RedBean PHP does not insert into two tables

Tags: php, mysql, insert, foreign-keys, redbean

I have two MySQL tables:

```
user

email
```

email table has a foreign key from user. I insert a record in to user table and get the insert id then insert in to email table.

I do this in RedBean like this

```
$user = R::dispense('user');
$user->name = 'John' ;

$email = R::dispense('email');
$email->email = $this->Email;
$email->user_id = R::store($user);

R::store($email);
```

But only user table is filled. No record has entered in to the email table.

What could be the issue here?

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`User`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`User` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `middlename` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `gender` ENUM('m','f') NULL DEFAULT 'm',
  `birthday` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `profilepic` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `datecreated` DATETIME NULL,
  `lastlogin` DATETIME NULL,
  `lastactive` DATETIME NULL,
  `mobilePhone` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `businessPhone` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `homePhone` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `faxNumber` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `drivingLicence` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `passportNum` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `bloodgrp` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And the email table

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`email`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`email` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `verifyCode` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `verified` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `User_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `User_id`),
  INDEX `fk_email_User1_idx` (`User_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_email_User1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`User_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`User` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

besides when I enter raw mysql, the insert works as expected. I think there is something wrong with my redbean usage. I've searched many places but I cannot figure this out.

Comment: Great stuff. I don't know RedBean, but I'd try temporarily dropping the constraint in the email table, and then trying the code again. Perhaps it is failing on this constraint silently? Also, ensure your on-screen error/warning reporting is enabled in PHP.

Comment: Ah! You need to set an `email` field before saving, since it is `NOT NULL`. I thought I'd found your code containing it, but no.

Comment: oh sorry. it was in the code. I thought it wasn't important.

Comment: @halfer thanks for your suggestion. After completing removal of all constraint the error resolve. but i have another question. in that email table a field named '_user_id' automatically created, without my knowledge. Is there a possibility for that. Please can you help me.

Comment: Do put your constraints back though, they are there for a reason. Work out what is failing (there should be a log in RedBean somewhere) and fix that. As for "Is there a possibility for that", I don't follow what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the lines

```
$email->user_id = R::store($user);
R::store($email);
```

to

```
$user->email = $email;
R::store($user);
```

and the relationship will be created automatically, assuming you are in fluid mode.

The Redbean engine will create the foreign key relationship and set a column in *email* table called *user_id* for you. You don't even have to store the **$email** object, that happens when the **$user** object is stored.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're interfering with the one-to-many relation functionality that is part of RedBean: http://redbeanphp.com/adding_lists. When you add relations using `$obj -> ownChild`, you are actually setting `child_id` in your object. By directly setting `child_id`, you're creating a field that RedBean chooses to retrieve through an own-list. However, this is just a hunch - I'll test this next time I'm at my development machine and update this answer.